# rotate a string in haskell with some exceptions

Tags: haskell

I want to rotate a string in haskell, so if I give "Now I  want to scream" to rotate [[want to scream now I],[scream now I want to]] , if the string start with "I" or "to" then must eliminate it. Till now I still have problems with the rotation.

```
reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = unwords . reverse . words

shiftt :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
shiftt l n = drop n l  ++ take n l

rot::String->[String]
rot l = [ reverseWords l i | i <- [0 .. (length l) -1]]
```

Comment: Consider the simplest shift, just taking the head and placing it after the tail.  This can be accomplished pretty easily with pattern matching.  Then take a look at the `iterate` function, it will repeatedly apply a function to an input, so `iterate (+1) 0` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`.  How can you use it to your advantage?

Comment: In `rot`, you are giving `reverseWords` two arguments, but it only takes one.  Also, I don't know what rotating has to do with reversing.  I think you want to break the string up into a list of words and then call `shiftt` on that list.

Answer (score 0):

create a list of all rotations, then filter out based on your predicate.  For example,

```
rotations x = take (length x) $ iterate rot1 x
        where rot1 = drop 1 x ++ take 1 x


filteredRots = map unwords . filter (\x -> length (head x) > 2) . rotations . words
```

and use as

```
> filteredRots "Now I want to scream"

["Now I want to scream","want to scream Now I","scream Now I want to"]
```

Prelude>